# Task.delay problems in this situation

Tags: c#, async-await, task

im new to the tasks so i decided to write a simple method here

```
        static async Task Work()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("download started");

            await Task.Run(async () => {
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{i}: is downloading");
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            });

            Console.WriteLine("done");
        }
```

calling here

```
        static void Main()
        {
            Work();
        }
```

the problem here is the output

expected output:

```
starting 
1
2
...
9
done
```

actual output:

```
download started
0: is downloading
```

i assume there is a duplicate post for this simple scenario, but i could not find it...

Comment: How are you calling this method? BTW the return type should be `Task` instead of `void`

Comment: @Jota.Toledo changed void to Task and added the place where i call my method

Comment: You are not waiting for `Work` to complete

Comment: You need to `await` the `Task` returned from `Work()` so you can change to `async Task Main()` and then `await Work()`. If you don't `await` `Work()` then the program finishes before `Work` completes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main thread in a Console application is special. Since it is the only foreground thread, when it exits, the entire application exits.

If you are using C# 7.1 or newer, you can specify an `async Task Main` method as such:

```
static async Task Main()
{
  await Work();
}
```

Under the hood, this will block your main thread until the operation completes. For older versions of C#, you can do this yourself:

```
static void Main()
{
  Work().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Normally, [you do *not* want to block on asynchronous code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx); the `Main` method of a Console application is an *exception* to this rule.

Comment: Main in a console application can be async in newer versions of C#. See linked duplicate.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary change your void Main to async Task main so i can accept it.